# How to get git to completely ignore a file?

Tags: git

I'm working on a collaborative project with a remote repo.  One of the source files in the repo is a "configuration"-type file, and I'd like to maintain my own local copy of the file that is different from the one in the remote, without git looking at the file.  That is, I don't want git to track the file; I don't want it to be committed if I use `git commit -a`; and I definitely don't want it pushed when I used `git push` to the remote.  I also don't want to delete it from the remote repo, so `git rm --cached` would be wrong.

A couple places (including one on StackOverflow) suggested using `git update-index --assume-unchanged <config-file>`.  This seemed to work; if I use `git status`, the file isn't listed as modified, and `git commit -a` doesn't try to commit it.  However, git is still preventing me from switching branches locally, between "master" and my working branch.  If I try `git checkout master` to go from a working branch to the master, or vice versa, I get

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout: 
    <config-file> 
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
```

`git checkout -f` doesn't help:

```
error: Entry '<config-file>' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
```

It seems that to switch branches, I have to rename the file, use `git checkout`, then rename it back, every time I switch.  This is not going to be acceptable.  Neither is using another command like `git stash` every time I want to switch branches, which is something I need to do a lot.

The file is already listed in my `.gitignore`.

How can I get git to completely ignore my file?

Comment: Would an extra Command be OK for you?

Comment: @Alex Not if I have to do it every time I switch branches.  If it's something I can do less frequently, then maybe.

Comment: I actually have a similar problem. I'm wondering if one can have a branch you don't need to check out and keep that parallel to the history. so it would be something like `git commit-ignored && git checkout-ignore <new-branch>` which you would alias then and use together.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the problem is not in the tool, but in the process. I've had to deal with that before when deploying some apps and think the solution is this:

- move your `config` file to `config.sample` instead
- make sure your deployment/installation copies `config.sample` as `config` if it doesn't exist
- don't add `config` to git at all - it doesn't need to be tracked
- keep `config` in `.gitignore`, so that it's not committed by accident in the future

Comment: I could try to make the case to my colleagues that the file shouldn't be in the repo, and I probably will.  (Most likely we don't even need the sample file there.)  I'm just wondering whether there's a way to do this on my own.  Or whether git's behavior is a bug.